# How do I get formatted and indented JSON in .NET using C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I am using Json.Net to serialize XML into JSON. When I write the serialized string to a file it all comes in a single line. How do I get it to actually look like Json with the usual tabs and indentation?

Comment: Which classes are you using?  JSON.NET provides a few different options.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Set the JSON writer [`Formatting`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm) property to `Formatting.Indented`:

```
jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

The [`JsonConvert.Serialize*`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) methods also have overloads that take a `Formatting` enum (thanks John Flatness).

Documentation: [**Serialize an Object**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm)

Comment: The various `JsonConvert.Serialize*` methods also take `Formatting` as the second argument.

Answer (score 11):

For those who ask how I get formatted JSON in .NET using C# and want to see **how to use it right away** and **one-line lovers**. Here are the indented JSON string one-line codes:

There are 2 well-known JSON formatter or parsers to serialize:

### Newtonsoft Json.Net version:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObj, Formatting.Indented);
```

---

### **.Net 7 version:**

```
using System.Text.Json;

var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourObj, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```