# Converting XML into beautified JSON inside a Web API method

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am serializing `XML` into `JSON` with the help of `Newtonsoft.Json`. How can I get the proper beautified formatted response?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <FirstValue>One</FirstValue>
  <SecondValue>Two</SecondValue>
  <ThirdValue>14000</ThirdValue>
  <FourthValue>28</FourthValue>
  <FifthValue>0</FifthValue>
  <SixthValue>28</SixthValue>
  <Details>
    <Detail>
      <FirstValueDetail>One</FirstValueDetail>
      <SecondValueDetail>Two</SecondValueDetail>
      <ThirdValueDetail>7000</ThirdValueDetail>
      <FouthValueDetail>0</FouthValueDetail>
      <FifthValueDetail>14</FifthValueDetail>
      <SixthValueDetail>false</SixthValueDetail>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <FirstValueDetail>Two</FirstValueDetail>
      <SecondValueDetail>Three</SecondValueDetail>
      <ThirdValueDetail>7000</ThirdValueDetail>
      <FouthValueDetail>0</FouthValueDetail>
      <FifthValueDetail>14</FifthValueDetail>
      <SixthValueDetail>false</SixthValueDetail>
    </Detail>
  </Details>
</Response>
```

**Response Class**

```
public class QuotationResponse
{
    public string ResponseInJson { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my API method which creates the response:

```
public static async Task<QuotationResponse> GetQuotationAsync(QuotationRequest quotationRequest)
{
    QuotationResponse quotationResponse = new QuotationResponse();
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(restResponse.Content);
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlDoc, 
    // this formatted the JSON until I got the printed response in postman
    Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented); 
    //here I assigned string to ResponseObject's member (ResponseInJson) which is also string
    quotationResponse.ResponseInJson = jsonText;
    return quotationResponse;
}
```

How would I correctly save the JSON into that response string?

**JSON return**

```
{
  "ResponseInJson": "{\"?xml\":{\"@version\":\"1.0\",\"@encoding\":\"utf-8\"},\"Response\":{\"@xmlns:xsi\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\",\"@xmlns:xsd\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\",\"@xmlns\":\"http://tempuri.org/\",\"FirstValue\":\"One\",\"SecondValue\":\"Two\",\"ThirdValue\":\"14000\",\"FourthValue\":\"28\",\"FourthValue\":\"0\",\"FifthValue\":\"28\",\"Details\":{\"Detail\":[{\"FirstValue\":\"Two\",\"SecondValue\":\"Three\",\"ThirdValue\":\"7000\",\"FourthValue\":\"0\",\"FifthValue\":\"14\",\"SixthValueDetail\":\"false\"},{\"FirstValue\":\"Threww\",\"SecondValue\":\"Four\",\"ThirdValue\":\"7000\",\"FourthValue\":\"0\",\"FifthValue\":\"14\",\"SixthValueDetail\":\"false\"}]}}}"
}
```

However before assigning the json to string it shows fine in debugger

```
{"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"utf-8"},"Response":{"@xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","@xmlns:xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema","@xmlns":"http://tempuri.org/","FirstValue":"One","SecondValue":"Two","ThirdValue":"14000","FourthValue":"28","FifthValue":"0","SixthValue":"28","Details":{"Detail":[{"FirstValueDetail":"One","SecondValueDetail":"Two","ThirdValueDetail":"7000","FouthValueDetail":"0","FifthValueDetail":"14","SixthValueDetail":"false"},{"FirstValueDetail":"Two","SecondValueDetail":"Three","ThirdValueDetail":"7000","FouthValueDetail":"0","FifthValueDetail":"14","SixthValueDetail":"false"}]}}}
```

Expected JSON output is:

```
{
    "?xml": {
        "@version": "1.0",
        "@encoding": "utf-8"
    },
    "Response": {
        "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "@xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
        "@xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/",
        "FirstValue": "One",
        "SecondValue": "Two",
        "ThirdValue": "14000",
        "FourthValue": "28",
        "FifthValue": "0",
        "SixthValue": "28",
        "Details": {
            "Detail": [
                {
                    "FirstValueDetail": "One",
                    "SecondValueDetail": "Two",
                    "ThirdValueDetail": "7000",
                    "FouthValueDetail": "0",
                    "FifthValueDetail": "14",
                    "SixthValueDetail": "false"
                },
                {
                    "FirstValueDetail": "Two",
                    "SecondValueDetail": "Three",
                    "ThirdValueDetail": "7000",
                    "FouthValueDetail": "0",
                    "FifthValueDetail": "14",
                    "SixthValueDetail": "false"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947005/how-to-turn-on-indentation-when-writing-json-using-json-net

Comment: Where exactly does it show fine? What do you do to it afterwards? Where does it show in the other form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn on indentation when writing JSON using Json.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947005/how-to-turn-on-indentation-when-writing-json-using-json-net)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen in `Text Visualizer` before handing over to response string variable which show result in postman

Comment: @MatthewEvans and MightyBadaboom there actually doesn't resoled my issue. I also tried above solutions

Comment: This is not duplicate please, see the changes

Comment: Try `xmlDoc.Load(restResponse.Content);` instead of `xmlDoc.LoadXml(restResponse.Content);`

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid my issue is does not exist there.

Comment: I know, I ran your code, I just changed that part and the JSON within the string came intended. Give it a try.

Comment: it shows Bad Request. even xml was not loaded surprisingly

Comment: Can you share the link from where you are getting xml, So, it will help to regenerate the issue and trace the reason.

Comment: I am using localhost

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid please see the question now, I have made some changes

Comment: Are you using a framework such as Web API or MVC or WCF?

Comment: @BrianRogers yes.

Comment: @BrianRogers Web Api

Answer (score 0):

You said in the comments that you are using the Web API framework. (I've added this tag to your question.)  Web API assumes by default that it is responsible for serializing anything you give it.  That means that if you are manually serializing the data to JSON before you return it, then Web API will end up re-serializing that JSON, resulting in extra quotes, backslashes and loss of formatting.  That explains why you are getting the result you are seeing.

If you want the response to be exactly as the "expected JSON" shown in your question, then you either need to return the `XmlDocument` directly and let Web API serialize it, or you need to let Web API know you are handling the serialization manually by returning an `HttpResponseMessage` with `StringContent`.

Here is what your method should look like if you are returning the `XmlDocument` directly:

```
public async Task<XmlDocument> GetQuotationAsync(QuotationRequest quotationRequest)
{
    ...
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(restResponse.Content);  
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

Here is what your method should look like if you are returning an `HttpResponseMessage` instead:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetQuotationAsync(QuotationRequest quotationRequest)
{
    ...
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(restResponse.Content);  

    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(jsonText, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    return response;
}
```

Note: if you are using the first method and you want the response to be formatted nicely then you will also need to configure Web API's `JsonFormatter` to use indenting.  To do that, add the following to your `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting =
    Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
```