# How to make my json format become vertical way

Tags: c#, webapi

I have created a web api in asp.net web API 2 and i tried to show data in json format, it shows in horizontal way and it look like this in google chrome. I want to make the format like the image shows, the data in the image is doesn't matter, just a example to show the format.

I receive the following exception in google chrome:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">[{"UserId":23,"Name":"Emily","Access":3,"Mobile":"07419231"},{"UserId":31,"Name":"Lydia","Access":5,"Mobile":"67567587"},{"UserId":45,"Name":"Peter","Access":1,"Mobile":"90345853"},{"UserId":56,"Name":"Lebron","Access":4,"Mobile":"43895449"},{"UserId":73,"Name":"Amber","Access":0,"Mobile":"45788477"}]</string>
```

what i expect is something like this format in below:

```
[
    {
        "UserId":23,
        "Name":"Emily",
        "Access":3,
        "Mobile":"07419231"
    },
    {
        "UserId":31,
        "Name":"Lydia",
        "Access":5,
        "Mobile":"67567587"
    },
    {
        "UserId":45,
        "Name":"Peter",
        "Access":1,
        "Mobile":"90345853"
    },
    {
        "UserId":56,
        "Name":"Lebron",
        "Access":4,
        "Mobile":"43895449"
    },
    {
        "UserId":73,
        "Name":"Amber",
        "Access":0,
        "Mobile":
        "45788477"
    }
]
```

Here is my code in below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ApiTesting.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=DESKTOP-US2AF5N; database=Test; integrated security=true;");

        public string Get()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From TblDraft", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
            }
            else
            {
                return "No Data Found";
            }
        }
}
```

Edit

webapi.config added this syntax and it works

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
```

Comment: It shouldn't be nested inside an XML object. Instead, change the function to `public object Get()` and then `return dt;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn on indentation when writing JSON using Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947005/how-to-turn-on-indentation-when-writing-json-using-json-net)

Comment: When the browser gets a response, it doesn't know that you have returned it json. You will need to set a Content-Type header. This can be done 1) using @Charlieface s answer, or 2) by setting HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContentType = new StringValues("application/json");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use the `Formatting.Indented` parameter in your `SerializeObject` method. For more information, you can check the official documentation: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject_1.htm

What you should write is:
`return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);`

Comment: thank for the help, i figure it out i need to type this syntax in webapi.config to make it work